# Project templates in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, project-template

I have been trying to create a project template as per my infra guidelines. I am able to create the template from an existing project and can create a new project. The only issue I am facing is, one file content is not getting copied in the new project created with the user defined template. How can i transfer the content of the file (using project template).
Ex: when we create maven project in Intellij, we get a default pom.xml with some content. so in the same manner, I need a file.

Thanks
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

You can create github repository for this purpose with following structure:

```
project-template
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── package
│   │   │       └── package-info.java
│   │   │
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── application.properties
│   │   │
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │       │
│   │       └── WEB-INF
│   │           └── web.xml
│   │
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── package
│               └── package-info.java
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE.md
├── pom.xml
└── README.md
```

1. in IDEA select **`new` ⇒ `project from version control` ⇒ `git`**
2. clone this repository
3. remove **`.git`** subfolder
4. add/update/remove anything you need